# web forms, autofac, EF newing up models?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, webforms, autofac

I have a plan to rework my company web publishing platform with dependency injection because the coding references start to become a bit more complex.

In my research I have found a lot of examples regarding MVC but our intention at the moment is to rework the web platform's Business logic, DAL, Core etc.. with minimal UI interventions.

The architecture of the web platform is the following

1. SQL database
2. DAL (EF6)
3. Separated model from dal (poco)
4. Business Logic
5. CMS System
6. Front end (websites)

All in all separated projects with their own concerns but heavily referenced in between.

In my research to counteract heavy referencing and coupling I have chosen and followed the following example
[techbrij blog post](http://techbrij.com/generic-repository-unit-of-work-entity-framework-unit-testing-asp-net-mvc)

I do understand the concepts of abstraction and dependency injection well and have set up a test project but hit a snag.

In MVC the instantiating new data class (poco) is handled by the ActionResult

```
// POST: /Country/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Country country)
{
    // TODO: Add insert logic here
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _CountryService.Create(country);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(country);
}
```

so far so good if we use MVC. But if I use Webforms in order to insert new record my logic says that i need to instantiate a new class from the model fill its properties with specific values and pass it to the BLL/DAL or service layer:

```
public void InsertRecord()
{
    Country country = new Country();
    country.Name = "Some Country"; // or value from textbox..

    _CountryService.Create(country);
}
```

My question is:
Regarding webforms, is this OK or do I need to absrtact the model in order to inject the new data class without the "new" keyword

Since using the "new" keyword will not decouple my data model, how would you do this to achieve decoupling/ioc/di?

Comment: I don't think you are understanding dependency injection correctly, the country entity in the first sample has not been injected into the method, it has been passed in as a parameter.. it does however look like the _countryService class has been injected in. So in your web forms just accept a parameter and inject in another _countryService class.

Comment: So your concern is around `new Country()`? I am assuming that `Country` is a simple model, right?

Comment: Forgot to mention what you just did..  The MVC is newing up instance of country and passing as parameter as already filled data class..

Comment: Yes @YacoubMassad

I would like to avoid the newing up of the simlpe data class..

Comment: Is there a reason for that?

Comment: What about this way

`var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<Country>();
            var container = builder.Build();

            using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var country = scope.Resolve<Country>();
                country.Name = "some country";

                _countryService.Create(_country);
            }`

Comment: @YacoubMassad

I would like to decouple the model

Answer (score 0):

I think that's fine.  All the MVC framework is doing is newing up an instance of `Country` and matching up request parameters to your model's properties.  You might find a library that does the same in webforms but it would probably be overkill.

You could use a [factory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx) to abstract away the newing up but it's probably not for situations like you have here.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this article](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/). It differentiates between Injectables and Newables.

In my understanding, Injectables are classes that present behavior that you want to vary using DI. While Newables are simple classes that mostly contain data. They might contain some behavior that is internal to these classes (does not require external services to work) so you don't want to change such behavior using DI.

It seems to me that the `Country` class is a Newable. Therefore, it is perfectly normal to new it up via `new`.

Comment: `Country` is a poco, simple db representation.. so is it fine to newup?

Comment: Most probably Yes. You can include the definition of it in the question, that would make it easier to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided use repository pattern, I personally run away from it because it is all about hide your persistence tools, and if you hide your arsenal you lose the power it provides, apart from the probably unnecessary added complexity.

That said it is ok to manually create entities with *new* keywords, as long as you don't do it in the user interface class, for web forms you can use [Model View Presenter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14642/Model-View-Presenter-with-ASP-NET) combined with modern [Model Binding](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/presenting-and-managing-data/model-binding/retrieving-data) technics available for Asp.NET Web Forms. Presenter instantiate entities and interacts with persistent mechanisms (EF in your case).

You can decouple UI code from presentation code, presenter can lives in its own assembly and works with View Interfaces so you will inject concrete implementations with IoC.

Here is a very basic sample skeleton for a sample infrastructure representing the above:

```
public interface IView{}
public abstract Presenter<T> where T : IView
{
  public Presenter( T view){ View = view;}
  public T View {get;set;}
}
```

The services I build are about encapsulating *Business Logic*, *Application Logic*, etc. Again, you will want have to avoid hard references to concrete implementations of those services by working with interfaces and injecting concrete implementations with some IoC.